# How to create custom markup in Moodle theme settings?

Tags: themes, settings, moodle

I need to create a list of elements in a Moodle 2.x theme setting for which I will enable drag and drop re-ordering using Moodle's included YUI. My problem is that I don't know how to add my custom HTML/JS with a custom theme setting. I can only find documentation about adding settings with the pre-defined functions offered by Moodle, like `admin_setting_configtext` or `admin_setting_configselect` or `admin_setting_configtextarea` etc... How do I go about creating my own markup and use my own javascript in a theme setting page?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom page using Moodle, remember to require the config and set up the page:

```
require('../../../config.php');
require_once($CFG->libdir.'/adminlib.php');
//page definition
$PAGE->set_context(get_context_instance(CONTEXT_SYSTEM));
$PAGE->set_url('/theme/your_theme/admin/manage.php');
$PAGE->set_pagetype('theme_name_manage');
$PAGE->set_title('Manage your theme');
$PAGE->set_heading('Manage your theme');
echo $OUTPUT->header();
//Page content
echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

From this page you can define whatever setup or configuration you want. Finally you will want to add this page to the site admin navigation. Make sure you have a **settings.php** in the root directory of your theme and within that file you'll be wanting something like this:

```
if ($hassiteconfig) { // needs this condition or there is error on login page
    $ADMIN->add('themes', new admin_externalpage('theme_name', 
        'Manage Theme XYZ', 
        $CFG->wwwroot."/theme/name/admin/manage.php", 
        'moodle/site:config'));
}
```

**Themes** being the reference for the "themes" admin menu I figure you probably want to add this to. Remember that you should be using get_string in the above examples instead of hard-coding strings.